# R - How to rearrange entire rows using subset of data

Tags: r, comparison, row, col

I did a row by row comparison of colB of the 2 dataframes (both dataframes have the same ordered columns) I found out they are 98% identical and the only difference between 2 columns was some pairs of the values were switched like so:

```
df1$colB   df2$colB
   A          B
   B          A
   1          1 
   C          D 
   D          C
```

I took subset of when df1$colB is not equal to df2$colB

```
subset(df1, df1$colB != df2$colB)
```

Is there a way to use the row occurrence from the subset above to rearrange the entire rows of df1 so that all values from df1$colB and df2$colB now match?

Comment: It would help to add more of the pattern (perhaps 10 rows) and a few more columns. The right solution depends on the pattern so providing more details of the data will help.

Comment: You need to `order` both of them. The usual syntax is something like `mtcars[order(mtcars$drat),]`, which you'll need to do for both. Joins are also a possibility; `dplyr::anti_join` might be particularly useful.

Comment: Not very clear on what you want to do, but `merge` may lead you to right direction?

Comment: I simplified my question. I just want to know how to rearrange entire rows of a dataframe using the row occurrence from a subset of data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `subset` is the right function for this. It expects a logical vector as the second argument, (confusingly) also named "subset", and so has no ordering capability. Instead use `match` and `[`:

```
 df1[ match(df1$colB,  df2$colB), ]
  X1.5 colB
2    2    B
1    1    A
3    3    1
5    5    D
4    4    C
```

But after testing with a slightly more complex version of df2 that had NA's and other values in colB, I've decided that @Ananta's suggestion of `merge` is the safer way to go (but with df2 as the first argument to get the desired ordering):

```
> merge( df2,df1)[ names(df1) ]
  X1.5 colB
1    3    1
2    1    A
3    2    B
4    4    C
5    5    D
```